# Spring Autowired annotation with service implementation

Tags: spring

I have few doubts in the scenario below.

Having one interface and two implementation classes:

Interface:

```
interface ServiceInt
{
   public void save();
}
```

First implementation class:

```
Public class ServiceIntImpOne implements ServiceInt
{
   public void save()
   {
     // I am first service implementation
   }

}
```

Second implementation class:

```
Public class ServiceIntImpTwo implements ServiceInt
{
   public void save()
   {
     // I am Second service implementation
   }

}
```

Main class calling the save method of an implementation class:

```
Public class controller
{
   @Autowired ServiceInt;

   public void save()
   {
     ServiceInt.save()
   }
}
```

My Questions:

1. `ServiceInt.save()` – which save method of service class implementation will it invoke?
2. How we can use the save method implementation of the `ServiceIntImpTwo` class?
3. How does autowired work?

Comment: I edited my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ServiceInt.save() – which save method of service class implementation
>   will it invoke?

If you have two beans of the same type (beans defined via annotations or via xml) when you autowire that beans it will fail (throw exception), because Spring don't know what bean to inject.

```
caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
    No unique bean of type [ServiceInt] is defined:
```

> How we can use the save method implementation of the ServiceIntImpTwo
>   class?

If you defined your bean in a xml file, then you can use the id property

```
<bean id="beanTwo" class="ServiceIntImpTwo" />
```

then you can autowire using Qualifier annotation

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("beanTwo")
ServiceInt myServiceTwo;
```

if you are using annotations instead.

```
@Component
Class ServiceIntImpTwo impl...{}
```

Then you can autowire

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("serviceIntImpTwo ")
ServiceInt myServiceTwo;
```

> How does autowired work?

This you can read it on Internet.

http://memorynotfound.com/handling-multiple-autowire-dependencies-with-spring-qualifier/
https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-autowiring-qualifier-example/
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_qualifier_annotation.htm

Comment: You have mentioned @Qualifier("serviceIntImpTwo") but from where value "serviceIntImpTwo" will come because we have not defined this value anywhere in case of annotation.

Comment: By default Spring generate a name for the bean, and it is the same as the class but the first character in lower case

Comment: Thanks Much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have two implementation to one interface you will need to provide spring hint which one to use:

1. you can use `@Qaulifier` annotation
2. you can use `@Profile` and choose the active profile.